# activerecordでデータのスペースを無視して検索

Tags: rails-activerecord

http://tutty.info/521
このようなクエリをActiverecordで実行するにはどうしたらよいでしょうか

Answer (score 1):

ActiveRecord (とAREL) だけで無理矢理書こうとするとこんな感じになりますが、直接SQLを書いてしまう方が分かりやすいと思います。

```ruby
Item.where(
  Arel::Nodes::NamedFunction.new(
    "REPLACE", [
      Arel::Nodes::NamedFunction.new(
        "REPLACE",
        [Item.arel_table[:name], "　", ""]
      ),
      " ", ""
    ]
  ).matches("Foo%")
)
```

生成されるSQL文:

```sql
SELECT "items".* FROM "items"
WHERE REPLACE(REPLACE("items"."name", '　', ''), ' ', '') LIKE 'Foo%'
```

(ユーザからの入力などによって) 動的に条件を変更する場合には良いかもしれません。

Answer (score 0):

[`where`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/where)、または[`find_by_sql`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Querying/find_by_sql)を使ったらどうですか？

```
T.where("REPLACE(REPLACE(key,' ',''),'　','') LIKE ?", "%検索文字列%")
T.find_by_sql("SELECT key, value FROM t WHERE REPLACE(REPLACE(key,' ',''),'　','') LIKE ?", "%検索文字列%")
```